# Is there a way to access the initializer list when inheriting constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, initialization

I am currently working on a class hierarchy, where a class `B` inherits from `A` and uses the feature of C++ which allows to inherit constructors directly by typing:

```
using A::A;
```

rather copying all existing constructors. Is there a way to initialize class attributes of class `B`, that would otherwise be initialized by the initialization list?

The class hierarchy looks like the following, without using the constructor inheritance, and compiles fine:

```
class A
{

public:
    A (int a)
    {}
};

class B
:
public A
{
    public:
    B (int a)
    :
        A(a),
        blubb(a)
    {}
    float blubb;
};
```

Using constructor inheritance and the answer suggested by Revolver_Ocelot, the code looks like the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    A (int a)
    {}
};

class B
:
public A
{
    public:
    using A::A;
    float blubb {a};
};
```

Which gives the following compile time error message:

```
foo.cpp:21:22: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
     float blubb {a};
                  ^
foo.cpp:21:23: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘float’ in initialization
     float blubb {a};
                   ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use initialize class variables [through brace or equals initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) which will be used when otherwise member would be default initialized:

```
class B : public A
{
    using A::A;
    MyComplexType foo {ConstructorArgument1, ConstructorArgument2};
};
```

EDIT: due to new circumstances I will add new info.

In case you mentioned, there is no other choice, but to create your own constructor with signature you want if you want to have access to base class constructor argument. However this does not mean you have to duplicate code. Instead you can delegate most of the work to base class constructor, keeping only class B stuff in class B:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
    using A::A;
    B(int a) : A(a), blubb(a)
    {}
    float blubb;
};
```

If constructor argument is used to initialize some member in class A and derived class has access to that member, you can use that member to initialize derived class member:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    int y;
    public:
    A(int a) : y(a)
    {}
};

class B : public A
{
    int z {y};
    public:
    using A::A;
};
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't seem to work, have a look at the edited question. I have added two examples and the error messages.